# Unexpected execution order when pattern rule depends on another pattern rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm having trouble getting targets to execute in the order I expect. This is my `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: deploy.%
deploy.%: DEPLOY_ENV=$*
deploy.%: fetch.% publish
    @echo "[deploy] $(DEPLOY_ENV)"

.PHONY: publish
publish:
    @echo "[publish]"

.PHONY: fetch.%
fetch.%: DEPLOY_ENV=$*
fetch.%:
    @echo "[fetch] $(DEPLOY_ENV)"
```

This is the command I'm running:

```
make deploy.dev
```

##### Desired output

I want the `fetch` target to run **before** `publish`, like this:

```
[fetch] dev
[publish]
[deploy] dev
```

##### Actual output

Make always runs the `publish` target first:

```
[publish]
[fetch] dev
[deploy] dev
```

##### Debug output

```
$ make --debug=i deploy.dev
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File `deploy.dev' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for `deploy.dev'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `dev'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `fetch.dev'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `deploy.dev'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `deploy.dev,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `deploy.dev'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/deploy.dev,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `deploy.dev'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/deploy.dev'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `deploy.dev'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.deploy.dev'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `deploy.dev'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.deploy.dev'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `dev'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `fetch.dev'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `fetch.dev'.
  Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `dev'.
 Trying rule prerequisite `publish'.
 Found an implicit rule for `deploy.dev'.
   File `publish' does not exist.
  Must remake target `publish'.
[publish]
  Successfully remade target file `publish'.
  File `fetch.dev' does not exist.
 Must remake target `fetch.dev'.
[fetch] dev
 Successfully remade target file `fetch.dev'.
Must remake target `deploy.dev'.
[deploy] dev
Successfully remade target file `deploy.dev'.
```

Comment: If `fetch` needs to be built before `publish` is, then `publish` should have `fetch` as a prerequisite.  If need be, you can hack around that with recursive `make`, but you should consider it a red flag if you are unable to express a correct and complete set of prerequisites to `make`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it is impossible to formulate the dependency of `publish` on the `deploy`-selected `fetch` target as a pattern rule. You can help yourself here tho, with a bit of programming. We select those given goals (from the command line) which match a `deploy.%` pattern and substitute them to make `fetch.%` prerequisites of them:

```
.PHONY: deploy.%
deploy.%: DEPLOY_ENV=$*
deploy.%: fetch.% publish
    @echo "[deploy] $(DEPLOY_ENV)"

.PHONY: publish
publish: $(patsubst deploy.%,fetch.%,$(filter deploy.%,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    @echo "[publish]" $^

.PHONY: fetch.%
fetch.%: DEPLOY_ENV=$*
fetch.%:
    @echo "[fetch] $(DEPLOY_ENV)"
```